# Not able to import SVG image into my typescript application

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to import an image (SVG) into my typescript application

```
import  * as logo from './images/logo';    
export default class App extends React.Component<{}, {}>{
    render() {
        return (
                <div className="App">
                    <header className="App-Header">
                        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
                        <h1 className="App-tite">Welcome to React</h1>
                    </header>
                </div>
        );
    }
}
```

but typescript still throws the error

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/App.tsx:3:24 
    TS2307: Cannot find module './images/logo'.
```

I have a directory called images in the same location as App.tsx and it does have a logo.svg. In my webpack.config.js I also have a entry

```
resolve: {
  extensions: [".js", ".tsx", ".css", ".svg"]
}
```

I googled and found this thread https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-React-Starter/issues/12
But I don't know where to put `globals.d.ts` file (as recommended in the last post)

Also why is importing a simple image so hard?

Here is my repo

https://github.com/abhsrivastava/redux-tutorial

Comment: Can you show the file tree, please?

Comment: https://github.com/abhsrivastava/redux-tutorial

Answer (score 1):

One way of easily importing inline SVG files would be to make use of this package called [svg-inline-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg-inline-react), which wraps your SVG into a component.

You can try installing it

```
npm i svg-inline-react
```

And on your component,

```
import InlineSVG from 'svg-inline-react';
import logo from './images/logo.svg';    

export default class App extends React.Component<{}, {}>{
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-Header">
          <div className="App-logo" /> 
            <InlineSVG src={logo} />
          </div>
          <h1 className="App-tite">Welcome to React</h1>
          </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

In addition, you might need to configure your `webpack.config` by adding an additional rule.

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  module: {
    rules: [
      //...
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,use: 'svg-inline-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

And then, you might need to declare the typings too.

```
interface SvgInlineReactProps {
  src: string;
  raw?: boolean;
  element?: string;
}

declare module 'svg-inline-react' {
  export default class InlineSVG extends React.Component<SvgInlineReactProps, any> {
  }
}
```

Comment: This didn't solve my problem. I am still getting the error `ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/App.tsx:4:18 
    TS2307: Cannot find module './images/logo.svg'.`

Answer (score 1):

There is a couple of things, one of them is that your import is missing the extension, and by default it will try to look for a .ts file. Since you are importing the svg, you should do something like

`import Logo from './images/logo.svg';`

The other thing is, like you mentioned it yourself, you are missing a definitions file for that logo. You can either, next to `logo.svg`, create a `logo.svg.d.ts` or somewhere in your application create the `globals.d.ts` (it can be any name, any location)

Keep in mind that if you declare the module wrong, it will still not find it

The safest way is `declare module '*.svg';` inside the global definitions file

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing a typescript application, I suggest you use the microbundle package bundler make configurations easier. Microbundle is a “zero-configuration bundler for tiny modules".It’s a wrapper around rollup with sane defaults nice outputted size stats, multiple target formats (ES modules, CommonJS, UMD).

If you want to take a look  https://github.com/developit/microbundle

--external flag to specify external dependencies

*package.json*

```html
{  
  "name": "",
  "author": ",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "source": "src/index.tsx",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "exports": "./dist/index.modern.js",
  "unpkg": "dist/index.umd.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "microbundle watch --external .*/font/.*,.*/style/.*",
    "build": "microbundle"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "microbundle": "^0.13.0"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "license": "ISC"
}
```